# in c++ how to add a linked list at the end of a static array?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
using namespace std;

struct Package_Node
{
    int bar_code;
    float package_weight;
    struct Package_Node *next_packaged;
};

struct Key_Node
{
    int key;
    struct Package_Node *next_package;
};

Key_Node *keyMain=0;

int weightTemp=0,barcodeTemp=0,keyTemp=0,N=0,X=0,max_value=0,optionChosen=0,optionChosenTwo=0;
float tempWeight;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    do
    {
        cout << "1 - Enter Number of keys and the Max Value\n2 - Enter Number of Packages (N)\n";
        cout << "3 - Create Array of Keys\n4 - Organize Packages\n5 - Table Stats\n6 - Clean Table\n7 - Exit\n\n";
        cin >> optionChosen;
        switch(optionChosen)
        {
        case 1://entering keys and max values
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Number of Keys: ";
            cin >>X;
            cout <<"\nEnter Max Value of the Barcode: ";
            cin >>max_value;
            break;
        }
        case 2://enter number of packages.
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Number of Packages: ";
            cin >> N;
            break;
        }
        case 3://create array of keys.
        {
            //Key_Node *keyMain = new Key_Node[X];
            keyMain= new Key_Node[X];
            for(int i=0;i<X;i++)
            {
                keyMain[i].key=i;
                cout << keyMain[i].key<<endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {


                for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                {
                    barcodeTemp = rand() % max_value + 1;

                    keyTemp = barcodeTemp % X;

                    tempWeight = rand() % 500 + 1;

                    keyMain[keyTemp] = new Package_Node;

                    Package_Node->bar_code=barcodeTemp;
                    Package_Node->package_weight=tempWeight;
                    Package_Node->next_packaged=NULL;

                }
                for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                {
                    cout << totalPackages[i].bar_code <<endl;
                    cout << totalPackages[i].package_weight << endl;
                }



                cout << keyTemp;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
    }while(optionChosen!=7);
}
```

I am sort of confused here. `keyMain` is a static array.`keyMain[1]`, `keyMain[2]` etc. will point to a linked list that is made using `Package_Node`. The index of `keyMain` where the `new package_node` will be added is determined by `keyTemp`. But it seems like thats a far cry. Seems like the code I have written is not working. What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas? Please do not use vectors as this is for a class project and we wont talk about vectors at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keyMain is a static array".  It looks  a lot like it's just a non-static pointer to some dynamically-allocated memory...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `keyMain` is a static array but the `next_package` pointer will point to NULL and a dynamic array of `Package_Node` will be added as necessary

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you attempt this:

```
keyMain[keyTemp] = new Package_Node;

Package_Node->bar_code=barcodeTemp;
Package_Node->package_weight=tempWeight;
Package_Node->next_packaged=NULL;
```

That's not going to work.  This is the basic idea:

```
Package_Node *n = new Package_Node;
n->bar_code = barcodeTemp;
n->package_weight = tempWeight;
n->next_packaged = NULL;
keyMain[keyTemp].next_package = n;
```

Now you have a single-element list on each item in your `Key_Node` array.  If you want to add to those lists, then normal list-based algorithms apply.

But it looks like you are trying to use this as a hash array.  That means you want to append (or prepend) to your list.  Prepending makes for more readable code.  I'll do that, and if you want to append then that's an exercise for you.

```
// Do this instead of setting it to NULL (from previous code example)
n->next_packaged = keyMain[keyTemp].next_package;
```

In the above example you MUST initialise `next_package` to NULL when you create the `keyMain` array.  Currently you don't do this.  Since this is C++, it would be a good idea to familiarise yourself with [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

Finally, the following code doesn't make sense:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cout << totalPackages[i].bar_code <<endl;
    cout << totalPackages[i].package_weight << endl;
}
```

What you need to do (unless you are storing an array somewhere called `totalPackages`) is to iterate through your `keyMain` array and print out all the lists:

```
for(int i=0;i<X;i++)
{
    Package_Node *p = keyMain[i].next_package;
    while( p != NULL ) {
        cout << p->bar_code << endl;
        cout << p->package_weight << endl;
        p = p->next_packaged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This section does not look right

```
keyMain[keyTemp] = new Package_Node;
Package_Node->bar_code=barcodeTemp;
Package_Node->package_weight=tempWeight;
Package_Node->next_packaged=NULL;
```

it should be something like

```
keyMain[keyTemp].next_package = new Package_Node;
keyMain[keyTemp].next_package->bar_code=barcodeTemp;
keyMain[keyTemp].next_package->package_weight=tempWeight;
keyMain[keyTemp].next_package->next_packaged=NULL;
```

Also the way you are calculating keyTemp

```
barcodeTemp = rand() % max_value + 1;    
keyTemp = barcodeTemp % X;
```

does not seem right as depending on what you enter in for the max_value it may be greater than X, the size of you array.